# Bizagi integration with Alfresco Community 5.2

Tags: integration, alfresco, business-process-management, bizagi

Guys!
    I'm new to Bizagi and I'm trying to connect it to Alfresco Community 5.2 version. I have troubles with the url.
    I followed these steps:

```
http://help.bizagi.com/bpm-suite/en/index.html?setting_ecm_bizagi.htm

The problem is when I create new repository in the url field I'm putting this link: http://citstnlab02:9080/alfresco/cmis

and I get an error "Cannot connect with the specified repository". Also the link doesn't open in my browser - it gives me 404 error. I tried with couple more links like:
/alfresco/cmisws
/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.1/atom
/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.0/atom
/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.1/browser

and any of them is working. 

Can anyone tell me what url should I use and if I should make any additional changes to Alfresco?
Thank you in advance!
Best regards,
Albena Mincheva.
```

Comment: which version of alfresco you are using?

Comment: Alfresco Community 5.2.0

Comment: First of all you must enable alfresco-cmis by adding the following properties in 'alfresco-global.properties' file.                                          cifs.enabled=true
cifs.serverName=yourServerName
cifs.hostannounce=true, then check it.